# Recommendations for a ASP.NET Forum control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum, custom-server-controls

I am looking for a Forum server-side asp.net control that will integrate into my asp.net 3.5 site.

I've seen a ton over at www.asp.net in their gallery page, but almost none have ratings, so difficult to determine which are reliable and which will turn into a nightmare.

Recommendations?  Both free and paid components are welcome.

Comment: I'm interested in this AND in a Blog control.

Comment: sir I too am wanting this things.  Do you having a windows 7 control and a stack overlown control to go with them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're more than happy with "Jitbit Forum" http://www.jitbit.com/asp-net-forum/ , they have a free edition. Also this forum received a good review from Scott Hanselman on his blog - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselmanForumsAspNetForumFromJitBit.aspx

Comment: but that review is from 2007! Surely everything's changed since then?

Answer (score 1):

I've somewhat successfully integrated [Community Server](http://telligent.com/) another COTS CMS ([EPiServer](http://www.episerver.com/)) however it was far from smooth sailing. I found Community Server didn't integrate very well, was difficult to extend, sluggish and overloaded with far too many features for our needs.

PS. Sorry I didn't really answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try dmg forums ( http://www.dmgforums.com) they are quite easy to use

Answer (score 1):

We used CommunityServer for our initial site but we too found it bloated and slow. The company has since pivoted into a higher price point of the market (like %50k+), so it's effectively no longer an option, I suspect.